# How to list the rules for a security group using AWS java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk

The motivation here is to create a way to query my AWS environment for a dump of the configuration, serialize it, and then be able to run the query again to see any relevant changes.

I have the group identifiers from:

```
    private List<String> getSecurityGroups(InstanceNetworkInterface netInt) {
    List<String> result = new Vector<String>();

    List<GroupIdentifier> groups = netInt.getGroups();
    for(GroupIdentifier gi : groups) {
        result.add(gi.getGroupName());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the security group list with `describeSecurityGroup` on an `AmazonEC2` client object (whose instance is called `ec2` in my example).

```
public List<SecurityGroup> findAllSecurityGroups() {
    DescribeSecurityGroupsRequest securityRequest = new DescribeSecurityGroupsRequest();
    DescribeSecurityGroupsResult securityDescription = ec2.describeSecurityGroups(securityRequest);
    return securityDescription.getSecurityGroups();
}
```

Once you've a `securityGroup`, you can call `securityGroup.getIpPermissions()`, which gives you a `List<IpPermission>`.

You can check the [Javadoc](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html) for details, in particular about [IpPermission](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/IpPermission.html).

To give you an idea, a `toString()` representation of the `IpPermission` rule allowing a server to be contacted on port 80 by any IP, is the following:

```
{IpProtocol: tcp, FromPort: 80, ToPort: 80, IpRanges: [0.0.0.0/0], }
```

If you're interested only in a particular security group, you can use:

```
public SecurityGroup findOneSecurityGroupByName(String securityGroupName) {
    DescribeSecurityGroupsRequest securityRequest = new DescribeSecurityGroupsRequest();
    securityRequest.setGroupNames(Arrays.asList(securityGroupName));
    DescribeSecurityGroupsResult securityDescription = ec2.describeSecurityGroups(securityRequest);
    return securityDescription.getSecurityGroups().get(0);
}
```

Some basic integration tests, that should work in any Amazon EC2 account.

```
@Test
public void findsAllSecurityGroups() {
    assertThat(firewall.findAllSecurityGroups().size(), is(greaterThan(0)));
}

@Test
public void findsDefaultSecurityGroupByName() {
    SecurityGroup defaultGroup = firewall.findOneSecurityGroupByName("default");
    assertThat(defaultGroup.getGroupName(), is(equalTo("default")));
}

@Test(expected = AmazonServiceException.class)
public void throwsExceptionWhenfindingNonExistentSecurityGroup() {
    firewall.findOneSecurityGroupByName("inexistent");
}
```

Where `firewall` is an instance of the class that contains `findOneSecurityGroupByName` and `findsAllSecurityGroups`.